# Deterministic outputs based on non-connected inputs

Tags: one-way-function

I am looking for a one way function that can generate outputs **deterministically**. However, revealing any of the inputs dont allow the person to generate other inputs. 
***E.g:*** 
lets say we have a list of inputs: $i_{1},i_{2},i_{3},...$ that look completely random and a list of corresponding outputs: $o_{1},o_{2},o_{3},...$ that also look completely random which are each mapped by one way functions: $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},...$ 
These outputs can be generated without knowing the inputs so anyone should be able to deterministically generate the outputs (perhaps by knowing a public shared data which is used in the function). But if one of these inputs is revealed, it should not reveal the other inputs.
If it is not mathematically possible, I need a proof for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"public shared data" $\:$ = $\:$ the ordered pair whose entries are

[a key for a full-domain [statistically injective PRF](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454.pdf)] and [a [signature verification key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)]

$\hspace{.04 in}f$ is an arbitrary one-way function.

For each positive integer $j$, [$o_j$ is the value of the PRF at $j\hspace{.03 in}$] and [$i_j$ is [[the signature for $o_j$] concatenated with [the string of zeros whose length equals the length of that signature]]]

and $\hspace{.04 in}f_j$ is given by

if $\hspace{.04 in}f_j$'s input has even length and its left half is a valid signature for $o_j$

and its right half is all-zero then output $o_j$ else output $\hspace{.04 in}f$ of $\hspace{.04 in}f_j$'s input.

Comment: Why should the inputs left half be all zero? You said the input is the signature for $j$?

Comment: And how can someone generate the next output? He/she needs the signature of $j$. So if the key owner doesn't sign the next input $j$, the next output can not be calculated.

Comment: The inputs' left half being all zero is a way to make sure that the $\hspace{.04 in}f_j$s are one-way. $\;$

Comment: $o_j = j {}{}\;$

Comment: umm.. interesting! but now the outputs are not random then. They are like 1,2,3,..

Comment: _Now_ the outputs are random-looking to those who _don't_ have the shared data. $\:$ If you want it to look random to those who can deterministically generate them on their own, then you'll need either a [random oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) or a more precise definition of what you mean by that. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I just want them to look random for those who don't have the share. This works for me! Thanks. Do you have a bitcoin address so that I can tip you?

Comment: No. $\:$ Also, if you want the length of the $o_j$s to not depend on $j$, then you should instead [let the public shared data be an ordered _triple_ whose additional entry is a collision-resistant hash function] and $\hspace{.51 in}$ [let each $o_j$ be PRF(CRHF(j)) rather than PRF(j)]. $\:$ In that case, the "full-domain" part can be dropped. $\hspace{.31 in}$

Comment: Yea make sense. But the length doesn't matter really in my case.